# Java android ava.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Tags: java, android

I want to in finish Activity with result put a List of objets I created a class which look like this :

```
 public class Vals implements Serializable {
    public ArrayList<RowBean> data;

    public Vals(ArrayList<RowBean> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Next in activity (fragment) I did this when I finish my activity with result :

```
private void finishWithResult() {
    Bundle conData = new Bundle();
    conData.putString("param_result", counter + "");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtras(conData);
    ArrayList<RowBean> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    for(RowBean row : rowBeen){
        if(row.isSelected())
            rows.add(row);
    }
    intent.putExtra(ROW_BEAN_DATA, new Vals(rows));
    getActivity().setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

And in console I have :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.maps, PID: 10222 java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name =  com.maps.Utils.Vals) at 
android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1316) at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1264) at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618) at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692) at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636) at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7582) at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.finishActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2517)at android.app.Activity.finish(Activity.java:4324) at com.maps.Fragment.FragmentListOfAllObjetsToReportActivity.finishWithResult(FragmentListOfAllObjetsToReportActivity.java:156) at com.maps.Fragment.FragmentListOfAllObjetsToReportActivity.confirmChoose(FragmentListOfAllObjetsToReportActivity.java:160) at com.maps.Fragment.FragmentListOfAllObjetsToReportActivity.access$200(FragmentListOfAllObjetsToReportActivity.java:34) at com.maps.Fragment.FragmentListOfAllObjetsToReportActivity$3.onClick(FragmentListOfAllObjetsToReportActivity.java:102) at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
```

This is onActivityResult :

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 90:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Bundle res = data.getExtras();
                    String result = res.getString("param_result");
                    int count = Integer.parseInt(result);
                    if (count != 1)
                        tvChooseObjects.setText("Wybrano " + count + " obiekty");
                    else
                        tvChooseObjects.setText("Wybrano " + count + " obiekt");
                    rowBeen = ((Vals) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(FragmentListOfAllObjetsToReportActivity.ROW_BEAN_DATA)).data;

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rowBeen.size() + " " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                break;
        }
```

Comment: post your code of other activity where you are reading ROW_BEAN_DATA from intent

Comment: you want to pass object array list from one activity to another activity?

Comment: @Pehlaj I edit my post

Comment: @SachinShelar yes I want to do this

Comment: Does `RowBean` implement `Serializable` ?

Comment: @Titus yes RowBean implement Serializable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing **Serializable** implementation with **Parcelable** in **Vals** & **RawBean** classes

Replace getSerializableExtra with getParcelableExtra in *onActivityResult**

**Vals.java**

```
 public class Vals implements Serializable, Parcelable {
    public ArrayList<RowBean> data;

    public Vals(ArrayList<RowBean> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    protected Vals(Parcel in) {
        if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
            data = new ArrayList<RowBean>();
            in.readList(data, RowBean.class.getClassLoader());
        } else {
            data = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        if (data == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
            dest.writeList(data);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Vals> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Vals>() {
        @Override
        public Vals createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Vals(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Vals[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Vals[size];
        }
    };
}
```

**RawBean.java**

```
public class RowBean implements Serializable, Parcelable {

    public String title;
    public boolean selected;

    public RowBean(){
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public RowBean(boolean selected, String title) {
        this.selected = selected;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    protected RowBean(Parcel in) {
        title = in.readString();
        selected = in.readByte() != 0x00;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (selected ? 0x01 : 0x00));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<RowBean> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<RowBean>() {
        @Override
        public RowBean createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new RowBean(in);
        }

        @Override
        public RowBean[] newArray(int size) {
            return new RowBean[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: RowBean  is impements Serializable

Comment: Please make these classes parcelable, I have updated the answer, please check.

Answer (score 2):

Check out This example

```
public class Vals implements Serializable {
        int id;
        String name;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Vals(int id, String name) {

            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

Add DataWraperClass

```
public class DataWrapper implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<Vals > mServicesList;

    public DataWrapper(ArrayList<Vals > data) {
        this.mServicesList = data;
    }

    public ArrayList<Vals > getServicesList() {
        return this.mServicesList;
    }


    }
```

Create Intent Like This

```
DataWrapper mServiceListData = new DataWrapper(yourarraylist);
 mIntent = new Intent(KitVerfiyActivity.this, BeneficiaryDetailsActivity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("arr_list", mServiceListData);
 startActivity(mIntent);
```

get arraylist from Intent like this

```
 DataWrapper dw = (DataWrapper) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arr_list");
        mArrayCaseFullList = dw.getServicesList();
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Ok But I want to finish a activity with resulat and put ArrayList and in another activity in ActivityResult load this list

Comment: create intent with this --  mIntent.putExtra("arr_list", mServiceListData); put this intent into set result

Comment: android get Arraylist from onActivityResult intent like this --getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arr_list");

Comment: onActivityResult  when I try do this getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arr_list"); my apk is crash

Comment: I have a NullPointerException  here :                     ArrayList<Vals> mArrayCaseFullList = dw.getServicesList();

Comment: DataWrapper dw = (DataWrapper) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arr_list");
 Here I get a nullpointer

Answer (score 1):

Use Below method :

```
private void finishWithResult() {
        Bundle conData = new Bundle();
        conData.putString("param_result", counter + "");
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        ArrayList<RowBean> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        for(RowBean row : rowBeen){
            if(row.isSelected())
                rows.add(row);
        }

        conData.putSerializable(ROW_BEAN_DATA, new Vals(rows));
        intent.putExtras(conData);
        getActivity().setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        getActivity().finish();
    }
```

Retrieve your data like below code :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
rowBeen = ((Vals) bundle.getSerializable(ROW_BEAN_DATA);
```

Comment: Now in method onActivityResult I have nullpointer in this line :                     rowBeen = ((Vals) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(FragmentListOfAllObjetsToReportActivity.ROW_BEAN_DATA)).data;

Comment: I all time have nullpointer here :                     rowBeen = ((Vals) bundle.getSerializable(FragmentListOfAllObjetsToReportActivity.ROW_BEAN_DATA));